# ReactJS + Redux: How to trigger a button to open up a Mac Mail/Windows Mail with property email?

Tags: javascript, redux, reactjs

I have a button and a string property that holds an email address. Once the button is clicked, I want it to open up the Mac Mail/Windows Mail with the string property's email address inside the To:

How can I go about doing so? Any guidance or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `` window.location.href = `mailto:${this.props.email}` ``

```
class EmailButton extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }
    onClick(){
        window.location.href = `mailto:${this.props.email}`;
    }
    render(){
        return <button onClick={this.onClick}>EmailButton</button>;
    }
}
```

**[webpackbin demo](http://www.webpackbin.com/Vkc7NR6DZ)**

also you can use `` <a href={`mailto:${email}`}>EmailButton</a> ``